# Could not load [java.lang.Math]

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

i've upgraded my tomcat and jdk to apache-tomcat-8.5.12 and jdk1.8.0_121. but seems i hit error after start it.

Please refer my error below :

```
09-Jun-2017 00:37:31.776 INFO [Timer-0] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.lang.Math]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.lang.Math]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1158)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.calculateDeficit(GenericObjectPool.java:1647)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.ensureMinIdle(GenericObjectPool.java:1621)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.access$700(GenericObjectPool.java:190)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1758)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Math
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.calculateDeficit(GenericObjectPool.java:1647)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.ensureMinIdle(GenericObjectPool.java:1621)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.access$700(GenericObjectPool.java:190)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1758)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.lang.Math]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1158)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.lang.Math]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)
        ... 8 more
```

Comment: thtat is an instancce issue....

Answer (score 1):

This is a misleading error message by Tomcat and is not your root cause of the problem. Your instance has already stopped at this point due to something else going wrong.

Look in the Catalina (or any other) logs for something going wrong before this, which will be your root cause. This error message is just an annoying side-effect.

Lastly, a good rule when upgrading Tomcat is to remove the extracted webapp from the webapps folder to prevent caching issues and letting Tomcat do a fresh autodeploy the web archive.